# Pandas groupby calculate mean of every nth row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I have the following DataFrame:

| GroupID | Idx | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

and I would like to calculate the nth mean of every group, i.e. the mean of every group's first rows, second rows, ..., so that the result is

| GroupID | Idx | Value | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 0 | 3 | 4 | 2.33 |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2.33 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2.33 |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

I tried

```
def calc_nth_mean(df, grouper, col, n):
    return df.groupby(grouper)[col].nth(n).mean()


avg = []
for i in range(0, 90):
    avg.append(calc_nth_mean(data, "Group", "Value", i))
```

which works fine, but this does not seem to be the most efficient solution for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't have the 'Idx' column, you could `groupby` twice and use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) in the first `groupby` to get the position in the group:

```
df['Mean'] = df.groupby(df.groupby('GroupID').cumcount())['Value'].transform('mean')
```

But as you already have 'Idx', and assuming you can rely on this column to identify the position in the group (which might not be the case), just do:

```
df['Mean'] = df.groupby('Idx')['Value'].transform('mean')
```

output:

```
   GroupID  Idx  Value      Mean
0        0    1      2  6.000000
1        0    2      3  5.000000
2        0    3      4  2.333333
3        1    1      9  6.000000
4        1    2      4  5.000000
5        1    3      1  2.333333
6        2    1      7  6.000000
7        2    2      8  5.000000
8        2    3      2  2.333333
```